# How to change button hover color dynamically through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change all my buttons' hover color to match the theme of my websites.  I have a default color, but need to change it depending on the referring page.  I'm able to get the referrer page, but I can't figure out how to change the hover style.  This is what I have:

```
var btn = {
            hover: function (event) {
                event.target.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            },
            out: function (event) {
                event.target.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            }

        }

var element = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
        element.addEventListener("mouseover", btn.hover, false);
        element.addEventListener("mouseout", btn.out, false);

HTML:
<div>
   <button class="accountButton firstButton" id="FacebookExchange"></button>
</div>

Default Style:
    .unified_container .row .panel-default #api .localAccount .entry .buttons button {
        float: left;
        background-image: none;
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
        border-radius: 0.2rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: 400;
        height: inherit;
        line-height: 1.3333333;
        margin-top: 3rem;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        padding: 10px 16px;
        text-align: center;
        touch-action: manipulation;
        user-select: none;
        vertical-align: middle;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: inherit;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        color: #000;
        width: 100%;
    }
        .unified_container .row .panel-default #api .localAccount .entry .buttons button:hover {
            -moz-box-shadow: none;
            -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
            background-color: #d40000;
            color: #fff;
        }
```

The error message I get "element.addEventListener is not a function".

How do I change the button hover color?

PS  I can't write inline css, javascript or html in the buttons because the buttons are dynamically created by the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you are getting this error is because `document.getElementsByTagName('button')` returns an array of elements that have the tag name ***button***
So your variable ***element*** is an array.
To solve this error you need to identify which element in this array you are actually interested in adding a listener to.
For example if it is the first element then your code should look something like:

```
element[0].addEventListener("mouseover", btn.hover, false);
element[0].addEventListener("mouseout", btn.out, false);
```

if you want all your ***button*** elements to have the listeners then you can just use a simple foreach loop or map.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `document.getElementsByTagName('button')` you get an array of Nodes.
You need to iterate over the list and add the event listeners on each of them.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
elements.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener("mouseover", btn.hover, false);
    element.addEventListener("mouseout", btn.out, false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.